# Rails mailer sending Empty Body on EMail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, amazon-ec2, actionmailer, mandrill

I have following on config/application.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xxxxx.com' }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => 'xxxxx.com',
:user_name            => 'xxx.xxxxx@gmail.com',    
:password             => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
:authentication       => 'plain',
:enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

And in app/mailers/welcome_mailer.rb

```
 def welcome_email(user)    
     @user = user
     @lang=I18n.locale       
     if @user.email.present?      
       begin
       headers = {
        :subject       => welcome_email_subject(@user).to_s,
        :from          => ADMINISTRATIVE_EMAIL,
        :to            => user.email 
       }
       mail(headers) 
       rescue Exception => e
         abort      
       end
     end
 end
```

I have a template on /app/views/welcome_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb

I am using this mailer action for sending welcome emails along with confirmation link by using devise.For that I have done the following on /config/initializers/welcome_mailers.rb

```
module Devise::Models::Confirmable
def send_on_create_confirmation_instructions
  if self.email
     WelcomeMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver      
  end
end

def send_reset_password_instructions
  generate_reset_password_token! if should_generate_reset_token?
  WelcomeMailer.generate_password(self).deliver
end
end
```

Even though the development I have used same smtp configurations I am getting empty body for the mail sent on production and the same working fine in development(local).By the way my production environment is Amazon EC2. Initally 15 days before I have got the same issue and I solved by changing the smtp account.Now it is not happening in any order.Suggest with your feedback or comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the template route in the mailer config:

```
class WelcomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  ...
  self.template_root = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/views/mailers" # Rails.root in 3.x
  ...
end
```

Comment: Do you have any action_mailer settings in `config/production.rb`?

Comment: No,I have mailer settings only at config/application.rb